# In local I've folder which contains multiple csv files. using nifi how can I extact those files names and store it in other csv file?

Tags: apache-nifi

I've multiple csv files in the folder and I want to extract all files name with extension and store those list of files names in separate csv file.

[image: CSV files]

I want output as this.

[image: Expected Output]

how to do that in apache nifi?

I tried `listfile` processor but it is only giving files with data not file names. I only need file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just a step away from getting your solution. The `ListFile` processor is what you need to achieve what you are looking for.

You need to setup a `Record Writer` in your case you can use the `CSVRecordSetWriter`

> When a Record Writer is configured, a single FlowFile will be created that will contain a Record for each file in the directory, instead of a separate FlowFile per file.

[image: Listfile Properties]

[image: Output Flowfile]

From here on you can use `QueryRecord` processor and use a simple SQL query to get just the columns that you need for further processing.

[image: QueryRecord Properties]

[image: Output]